# Spark Job SUBMITTED but not RUNNING after submit via REST API

Tags: rest, apache-spark

Following the instructions in [this website](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/submit-spark-job-via-rest-api/), I'm trying to submit a job to Spark via REST API `/v1/submissions`.

I tried to submit `SparkPi` in the example:

```sh
$ ./create.sh 
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20211212044718-0003",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "3.1.2",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20211212044718-0003",
  "success" : true
}

$ ./status.sh driver-20211212044718-0003
{
  "action" : "SubmissionStatusResponse",
  "driverState" : "SUBMITTED",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "3.1.2",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20211212044718-0003",
  "success" : true
}
```

`create.sh`:

```sh
curl -X POST http://172.17.197.143:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
  "appResource": "/home/ruc/spark-3.1.2/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.1.2.jar",
  "sparkProperties": {
    "spark.master": "spark://172.17.197.143:7077",
    "spark.driver.memory": "1g",
    "spark.driver.cores": "1",
    "spark.app.name": "REST API - PI",
    "spark.jars": "/home/ruc/spark-3.1.2/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.1.2.jar",
    "spark.driver.supervise": "true"
  },
  "clientSparkVersion": "3.1.2",
  "mainClass": "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi",
  "action": "CreateSubmissionRequest",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "SPARK_ENV_LOADED": "1"
  },
  "appArgs": [
    "400"
  ]
}'
```

`status.sh`:

```sh
export DRIVER_ID=$1

curl http://172.17.197.143:6066/v1/submissions/status/$DRIVER_ID
```

But when I try to get the status of the job (even after a few minutes), I got a "SUBMITTED" rather than "RUNNING" or "FINISHED".

Then I looked up the log and found that

```
21/12/12 04:47:18 INFO master.Master: Driver submitted org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper
21/12/12 04:47:18 WARN master.Master: Driver driver-20211212044718-0003 requires more resource than any of Workers could have.
# ...
21/12/12 04:49:02 WARN master.Master: Driver driver-20211212044718-0003 requires more resource than any of Workers could have.
```

However, in my `spark-env.sh`, I have

```sh
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=10g
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
```

I have no idea what happened. How can I make it run normally?

Comment: Make sure you have 10G of memory as your spark-env.sh, and try to decrease appArgs from 400 to 10. seems you don't have resources to run the application.

Comment: @Yassine Abdul-Rahman `/proc/meminfo` shows that I have at least 4GB of free memory, then I change spark-env.sh to 1g and decrease the appArgs to 10. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: If this spark server has an UI, can you please go to executors tab and check if drivers and workers are properly spawned with enough threads for processing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've checked resources and You have enough. It might be network issue. executor maybe cannot connect back to driver program. Allow traffic on both master and workers.

Comment: I don't think it's the case because everything works well when I submit through `spark-submit` in the terminal.

Comment: What's more, I checked `$SPARK_HOME/logs` and find that only the master log has something about this driver and neither of the worker logs has been modified.

Comment: Okay, it turns out that you're right in some way. Someone opened a spark directly by java a few months ago, which occupied port 7077. I didn't find that until I mentioned that spark UI still worked even after I closed spark.